# How do i design a document validation component in J2EE?

Tags: xml, spring, excel, validation, jakarta-ee

I am a .NET developer who has to develop this component in a Java-ee web application :-

1. User will choose a file
2. This will either be a Excel file or an XML file
3. The component should check if the file has the pre-defined structure. Only certain kinds of files need validation. So use XSD for XML document and some structure definition for the Excel file. If any column name, size, value range , data type mismatch, report and abort.
4. Then validate the document against a set of validation rules. For this i am thinking of building a XML file/SQL table which has the list of methods which need to be run against this document to validate it. Report all exceptions , return values from each of these methods.
5. As and when developers think of a new validation, they will add a method to some class, and reference this method in the XML/SQL table so that the component picks them up at run time.

Is this a good plan or is it better to go with Spring or some such advanced J2EE functionality (which i have never used but need to learn) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If allways all valudation rules shold be checked (and there is no need to disable some in dynamic way (database) without code modification, then:

I would not use a database for (4) and (5). Instead I would use Annotations to mark the validator methods as well as to add meta information's (for example error messages)   to this methods.

If you use spring then I would implement this with a bean post processor. Or if this is to much work I would have a validator interface (and have one validation rule per implementing class) (the validator class must be stateless). Then I would make this class a spring bean (If you use xml configuration, you could use them for enabling/disabling the rules). Then one can let spring inject every validator `@Autowire List<ValidatorInterface> validators;`

Answer (score 2):

Instead use property file and put configuration there. Read property in your code and used accordingly for validation.For ex

```
allowed_filetype=xls,xml
```